# Python: Subprocess communication fails and Terminal crashes

Tags: python, ios, macos, terminal, lldb

I am working on a Python script for automated smoke and unit testing on mobile devices. I use [ios-deploy](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy) for the iOS solution. Because I try to kill the LLDB session before I terminate the test process, I use a pipe for communication between the processes. Here is a piece of code:

Pipe declaration:

```
    _pipe_cmd_rcv, _pipe_cmd_snd = Pipe()

    # Pipe to receive commands
    self._pipe_cmd_rcv = _pipe_cmd_rcv
    # Pipe to send commands
    self._pipe_cmd_snd = _pipe_cmd_snd
```

The part where I send the `exit` command to LLDB, followed by a `Y` to confirm the exit:

```
        self._pipe_cmd_snd.send("exit \n")
        self._pipe_cmd_snd.send("Y \n")
```

And finally the part where I want to receive the input:

```
    pcs = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdin=self._pipe_cmd_rcv, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

My intention is to send the `exit` command to the stdin of the process running LLDB, but unfortunately after the whole test process is finished, I can't use my Terminal anymore. If I type <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> it returns the prompt, and when I hit enter, it pastes the prompt as input. It is like it is stuck in a loop. I have to open a new Terminal window to use it "the normal way". And this is not desired, because the script will be used to run on a CI system. Can anyone figure out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have spawned the process with input through **self._pipe_cmd_rcv** but you are trying to send the input to that process via **self._pipe_cmd_snd**, so it's blocking there for input. Following might help.

```
    self._pipe_cmd_rcv.send("exit \n")
    self._pipe_cmd_rcv.send("Y \n")
```

Comment: This does not work, because a pipe declaration returns a tuple. You need the two ends of a pipe, one for sending and 1 for receiving. I want so send a command to the stdin of the process, not send from it